# How do I store a Python package on Gitlab and install it in a Conda environment?

Tags: python, bash, git, package, conda

I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://uoftcoders.github.io/studyGroup/lessons/python/packages/lesson/) to store and install my package using Git and pip:

I created a git repo of the project directory and used `pip` to install it from that repo. When I try to import my package, I got this error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statstemplate'`.

I ran `conda list` and my package is listed

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
... other packages ...
statstemplate           0.1                       <pip>
```

I tried to remove that package and try again by running `conda remove -n myenv statstemplate` and got an error

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment
  - measurements
```

I then tried installing the package in the tutorial just to prove to myself that it works and I got the same problem. I get the same error messages when I try to import the module in the tutorial and remove it from my conda environment.

Can somebody please explain to me what I did wrong?

(I do not just want to run `python setup.py install`. I'd like to store it in GitLab).